# How to pull a specific value from JSON dictionary?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

json information

```
{
    "list":[
        {
              "dt": 1490791600,
              "temp": {
                  "day": 58.26,
                  "min": 39.65,
                  "max": 67.37
              }
              "pressure": 999.65
         }
         {
              "dt": 1480878000,
              "temp": {
                  "day": 57.34,
                  "min": 40.11,
                  "max": 68.23
              }
              "pressure": 999.64
         }
      ]
}
```

my code

```
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = json.load(json_obj)

for item in data['list']:
        print item['temp']
```

output

```
{u'day': 58.26, u'min': 39.65, u'max': 67.37}
{u'day': 57.34, u'min': 40.11, u'max': 68.23}
```

How do I get the information for the day temperature (`u'day'` in my output)?

How do I assign a unique variable ex: day1= 58.26  day2= 57.34 to each day temperature?

Comment: Why not just try `temperature = item['temp']['day']`

Comment: @rozkosz That worked pretty well!  I guess my mechanical engineering background didn't really set me up well for this.  Do you know of any threads that would show me how to assign a unique variable to each temperature value?

Comment: The idea of using unique variables is an extremely poor one. Far more sensible to create a dict to hold the values like this temp_dict = {'day1': 58.26, 'day2': 57.34, ..., 'dayX': 99.99}. Now that you know how to get a value based on the key I think you should understand how to set and retrieve values in this dict?

Comment: @jwpfox thanks.  I'll need to practice with it some but should be able to figure it out